# Can we get a stored procedure call using Sql server profiler within another SP

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure named **CreateUpdateNewOrder** and i call another SP in it named **CreateClinicalDocument** Now i want to see what exact values my second SP is getting for execution. I can run a sql profiler tool to see what input values **CreateUpdateNewOrder** is getting but I can't think of any other way of getting input values for inner SP call other than print them in query. Anyone has better way to do it?

Comment: Consider using the `OUTPUT` clause: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run SQL Profiler and select the SPS template instead of the default one.This will show you every statement executed, even if it's inside a stored procedure.To use the SPS template you need to do the following:

1. File -> New trace
2. In the dialog that opens go to combo "Use this template" and select TSQL_SPs.
3. Now continue setting up your profiling session as you would normally.

Once you start the trace you will notice it's much more verbose. It will break down each procedure and will show what's executed line by line.Please let me know if you would need any other details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response but could you please explain a bit about SPS template or any documentation link will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ok, I'll assume you know how to use SQL Server Profiler in the default way (File -> New trace -> Click Run)

I'm editing the post to add how to select the SPS template

Comment: I haven't been around in my work place from last few days. I will test your solution and i know how to use SQL profiler in default way. So i will test SPs template thing for the first time.

Comment: @cristi71000 This still profiles the inner args as "@param".. any suggestions to see the value, this is only for debugging..I know I could PRINT/Dump to table etc.. just want to know if there is a profiler option

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you need to access and use the information, but it could be useful to log the values to a table.  You could also try Debug in SSMS and set appropriate break points.

Comment: I am currently using SQL SERVER 2005 and i am afraid I won't be able to use break points in this version.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the standard template in profiler you'll see that on the Events Selection tab under the Stored Procedures heading it only includes "RPC:Completed".  The T_SQL_SPs template includes "SP:Completed", "SP_Starting" and "SP:StmtStarting".   I believe you just need to include those in whatever template you choose.